# Why do I get an Error when I use the RequestHandler? Cefsharp Native Browser

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

Everytime I start my Project and return false in the OnBeforeBrowse-Methode I get an Error in the GetResourceRequestHandler. Screenshot down there. What should I add to GetResourceRequestHandler to save this problem.I dont know to go on, it would be great when somebody can post the fixed code-snippet down there. Hope you understand my Problem Thanks :D

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MaterialSkin.Controls;
using MaterialSkin.Animations;
using MaterialSkin;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace GaminglexikonApplication
{

public partial class Form1 : MaterialForm
{
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;
        CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("example.com");
        browser.MenuHandler = new MyHandler();
        browser.RequestHandler = new MyRequestHandler();
        panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
    }
    public class MyHandler : IContextMenuHandler
    {
        public void OnBeforeContextMenu(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model)
        {
            model.Clear();
        }

        public bool OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public void OnContextMenuDismissed(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
        {

        }

        public bool RunContextMenu(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model, IRunContextMenuCallback callback)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public class MyRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
    {

        public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isRedirect)
        {
            // You can check the Request object for the URL Here
            return false;
        }

        public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            // You can also check the URL here
            callback.Dispose();
            return CefReturnValue.Continue;
        }

        public bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            callback.Dispose();
            return false;
        }

        public bool OnOpenUrlFromTab(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public void OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
        {
        }

        public bool OnProtocolExecution(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string url)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public bool OnQuotaRequest(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, long newSize, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            callback.Dispose();
            return false;
        }

        public void OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
        {
        }

        public void OnRenderViewReady(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
        {
        }

        public void OnResourceLoadComplete(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, UrlRequestStatus status, long receivedContentLength)
        {
            // You can also check the request URL here
        }

        public void OnResourceRedirect(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, ref string newUrl)
        {
        }

        public bool OnResourceResponse(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
        {
            return false;
        }


        public IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
        {
            return null;
        }


        public void OnResourceRedirect(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, ref string newUrl)
        {
        }

        public bool OnSelectClientCertificate(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection certificates, ISelectClientCertificateCallback callback)
        {
            callback.Dispose();
            return false;
        }

        public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
        {
            // Open in Default browser
            if (request.Url.StartsWith("example.com"))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(request.Url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        public IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Return null in GetResourceRequestHandler and return false in GetAuthCredentials . Your code throws exceptions so of course your program crashes.

Comment: Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Instead of implementing IRequestHandler directly you can inherit from http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_Handler_RequestHandler.htm and only override the method you need